# pass param to javascript constructor function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    function check_and_kill(selector){
        (function checkState(selector){
            if(selector.attr('type')){ 
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        })(),

        kill = function(){
            if(this.checkState() == false){
                console.log('kill all')
            }
        }

    }
$('something').click(){
    check_and_kill($(this));
}
```

I try to make checkState as my constructor, the the second function which is kill react depends on the value returned by the constructor, but I can't pass the selector, it return undefined.

Comment: You shadow `selector` in the `checkState()` function, but do not pass a parameter. Anyways, your code looks quite strange.

Comment: this is because you are not passing it to IIFE. Pass selector to it. `(function(){})(selector)`

Answer (score 0):

Following is the simulation of both cases.

#### Code

```js
function Class(str){
 (function(str){
     document.write(str)
    })(str)                  // Binding value
}

function Class2(str){
 (function(str){
     document.write(str)
    })()                    // Not binding value
}

(function(){
 var a = new Class("Hello World. ");
    var b = new Class2(" Hello World ")
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't store the value from the constructor...

```
checkState = (function checkState(selector){
        if(selector.attr('type')){ 
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
})(),
```

or call the kill function... also you should take a long hard look at the syntax for your call to .click.... also .click doesn't have reference to a "this"

Here's a working example in the spirit of what you're trying to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/n2zk1wym/

Here's a working example that does what you're trying to do, without all the bells and whistles.  Your attempt to use the finer aspects of the javascript language are commendable, but totally unnecessary for this particular problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/2mL9jh2a/